# Is there an easier way of sorting Enum members in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I'm stuck with Python 2.7 for a project, and I have several `Enum`s for integrating a Python framework (OpenERP) with a legacy framework.  In Python 2, [`Enum`s are not ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405365/208880) by default:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Color(Enum):
...   RED = 1
...   GREEN = 2
...   BLUE = 3
... 
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.BLUE: 3>, <Color.RED: 1>, <Color.GREEN: 2>]
```

If order is important one has to manually add an `_order_ = 'member1, member2, member3'` attribute.

```
>>> class Color(Enum):
...   _order_ = 'RED GREEN BLUE'
...   RED = 1
...   GREEN = 2
...   BLUE = 3
... 
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.RED: 1>, <Color.GREEN: 2>, <Color.BLUE: 3>]
```

This works fine for smaller `Enum`s, but I have several that have between 10 and 50 names, and that is simply too many to either type or read or keep in sequence when names are added/removed.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Can you use the enum34 package? It has been backported to Python 2.7.

Comment: @Sebastian:  The example above is using the `enum34` package.  It's not obvious because `enum34` installs as `enum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of `aenum 2.1.2`<sup>1</sup> the `_order_` attribute can be a function; this function will be used as the `key` to `sort()` to put the `Enum` members in the correct order:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Pres(str, Enum):

    _init_ = 'value, precedence'        # footnote 2
    _order_ = lambda m: m.precedence    # footnote 3

    PRESIDENT = 'president', 1
    COUNSELOR_1 = 'first counselor', 2
    COUNSELOR_2 = 'second counselor', 3
    SECRETARY = 'secretary', 4

    def __repr__(self):
        "added so example below is clearer"
        return '<%s.%s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Pres)
[<Pres.PRESIDENT>, <Pres.COUNSELOR_1>, <Pres.COUNSELOR_2>, <Pres.SECRETARY>]
```

---

While I wouldn't call this next version easier, if you can't use `aenum`, and don't want to try and maintain a huge `_order_`, it is possible using the [Functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api):

```
Pres = Enum('Pres', (
        ('PRESIDENT', 'president'),          # comment here
        ('COUNSELOR_1', 'first counselor'),  # more comments here
        ('COUNSELOR_2', 'second counselor'), # you get the idea ;)
        ('SECRETARY', 'secretary'),
        ),
        type=str,
        )

def pres_repr(self):
    "added so example below is clearer"
    return '<%s.%s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)

Pres.__repr__ = pres_repr
```

Ugly, but it works.  However, it would not work if the `precedence` field was needed.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

<sup>2</sup> `_init_` is necessary in this case as I do not want the `precedence` value passed to the `str` constructor.

<sup>3</sup> the key function will be given one argument:

- no `_init_` -> a tuple of `(name, value)` where value may also be a tuple (it would have been in the example above)
- with `_init_` -> an `aenum.NamedTuple` with fields `name` plus whatever fields are in `_init_` (so `name`, `value`, and `precedence` in the example above)